# How to simulate type I error and type II error

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose $H_0: F_0$ and $H_1: F_1$, I want to simulate (lower bound of) the sum of type I($\alpha$) and type II($\beta$) error based on n observations. (Q:Am I posing the problem in the well-defined way?)

For simplicity, I am considering testing $H_0: \mu=0$ and $H_1: \mu=2$ for $F_0\sim N(0,1)$ and $F_1\sim N(2,1)$(Q: should $H_1$ be $\mu=2$ or just $\mu>0$?). For this setting, the minimum $\alpha+\beta$ occurs at the cut-off $\mu=1$. So maybe we can use this value to compare with test statistics($\bar{X}$)?

Then, how can I simulate the type I($\alpha$) and type II($\beta$) error? (I know the theoretical value of this sum is the area of the left tail of $F_1$ and right tail of $F_0$ separating from the cut-off point.)

Should I simulate say $n=100$ points, and 50 from $H_0$, and 50 from $H_1$(that is why I choose $H_1$ is $\mu=2$ rather than $\mu>0$, since I cannot simulate the later, right?). And count what is the misclassification rate, and that is the sum of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Is this idea right? Am I asking a well-defined question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, a conventional way to write a test of hypothesis is:
$H_0: \mu=0$ and $H_1: \mu \ne 0$ or $H_1: \mu >0$ or $H_1: \mu <0$ based on the interest of the study.

Let's define **Type I** error:
Probability of rejecting null hypothesis when it is **TRUE**.

**Type II** error:
Probability of not rejecting null hypothesis when it is **False**.

Let's test type I error:

To observe the type I error of a test we need to generate/simulate data from the same distribution that follows null hypothesis. Notice the following R code:

```
n=10000 # testing 10,000 times
t1err=0
for (i in 1:n){
   x=rnorm(100, 0, 1)
   if (((t.test(x, mu=0))$p.value)<=0.05) (t1err=t1err+1) 
}
cat("Type I error rate in percentage is", (t1err/n)*100,"%")
```

It should give you about 5% error as Type I error.

Let's observe Type II error:
To test Type II error we have to generate/simulate data from another distribution than that followed by null hypothesis. Notice the following R code:

```
n=10000 # testing 10,000 times
t2err=0
for (i in 1:n){
   x=rnorm(100, 2, 1)
   if (((t.test(x, mu=0))$p.value)>0.05) (t2err=t2err+1) 
}
cat("Type II error rate in percentage is", (t2err/n)*100,"%")
```

You will see 0.0%. As the variance is really low. If you increase variance to 5, you will see about 2% error as Type II error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! So if I want to find the minimum sum of T1 and T2 error, I need to try all the possible "0.05", say from 0.01 to 0.99, right? And ideally, the theoretical minimum occurs at $\frac{\mu_0+\mu_1}{2}=1$. So we expect that the simulated minimum value of the sum occurs around the cutoff probability corresponds to $\mu=1$, right?

Comment: The `rnorm()` function accept standard deviation (and not _variance_) as third parameter. Therefore we should say: If you increase **standard deviation** to 5, you will see about 2% error as Type II error.

Answer (score 3):

Just to replicate [this post](http://datacolada.org/archives/2799) dwelling on a different iteration of the same idea - in this case how quickly an unscrupulous researcher could generate throw-away pseudo-science with significant p values, I landed on this page, and learned from the accepted answer (+1).

It turns out the mean is $20$ as predicted; the median is $14$; and the mode **just $1.$** This is in keeping with the [right skewed distribution](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Skewness) on the histogram below.

Here is the code in R, and the results for mean, median and mode, which sounds like what you are asking in the follow-up comment:

```
set.seed(3141592)
firsthackingop <- 0  # Empty vec to collect number of studies before hitting the jackpot.
for(i in 1:1e5){     # The whole search for a sig p value will be done 100,000 times.
hackingwait <- 1     # The counting vector for every p-searching Safari.
  repeat{
  x=rnorm(100, 0, 1) # 100 draws from a norm dist as in @overwhelmed's answer.
  if(t.test(x, mu=0)$p.value > 0.05){hackingwait=hackingwait+1}else{break}
}
firsthackingop[i] <- hackingwait
}
mean(firsthackingop)
# [1] 20.17556
median(firsthackingop)
# [1] 14
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
Mode(firsthackingop)
[1] 1
hist(firsthackingop, freq = T, main = "No. t-tests before Type I Error",
          xlim=c(0,100), col = rgb(.2,.2,.8,.5), border = F,
          cex.axis=.75, cex.main=.9, xlab="", ylab="")
```

Here is the histogram:

[image]

---

It is interesting to note that this is simply the geometric distribution with $p=0.05$ defined as *The probability distribution of the number X of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success*, which mean is $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{0.05}=20;$ and with a mode of $1.$ The data generation in R is `v = rgeom(1e5,0.05) + 1` and here is the plot:

[image]

```
> Mode(v)
[1] 1
> mean(v)
[1] 20.12817
> median(v)
[1] 14
```