# How to simulate type I error for random-effects model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, simulation, random-effects-model, type-i-and-ii-errors

Building upon this post [How to simulate type I error and type II error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148526/how-to-simulate-type-i-error-and-type-ii-error). I would like to simulate type I error for a random-effects model I generated. The statistic of interest is standard deviations of the random intercept and random slope. Specifically, for random intercept, $H_{0}$: $\lambda_{0} =2$ and $H_{1}$: $\lambda_{0} \neq 2$; for random slope, $H_{0}$: $\lambda_{1} =1$ and $H_{1}$: $\lambda_{1} \neq 1$. I assume the test would be likelihood ratio test but please correct me if I am wrong. How do I assess type I error for the random-effects model I specified below:

```r
        set.seed(323)
        # The following code is to specify the structure and 
        # parameters of the random-effects model
        dtfunc = function(nsub){
          time = 0:9
          rt = c() 
          time.all = rep(time, nsub)
          subid.all = as.factor(rep(1:nsub, each = length(time)))
          
          # Step 1:  Specify the lambdas.  
          G = matrix(c(2^2, 0, 0, 1^2), nrow = 2)  
          int.mean = 251  
          slope.mean = 10  
          sub.ints.slopes = mvrnorm(nsub, c(int.mean, slope.mean), G)
          sub.ints = sub.ints.slopes[,1]
          time.slopes = sub.ints.slopes[,2]
          
          # Step 2:  Use the intercepts and slopes to 
          # generate RT data
          sigma = 30      
          for (i in 1:nsub){
            rt.vec = sub.ints[i] + time.slopes[i]*time + 
                       rnorm(length(time), sd = sigma)
            rt = c(rt, rt.vec)
          }
          
          dat = data.frame(rt, time.all, subid.all)
          return(dat)
        }
        
        #Here I run one random-effects model
        set.seed(10) 
        dat = dtfunc(16)
        lmer(rt~time.all + (1+time.all |subid.all), dat)
```

Assuming the test for significance is likelihood ratio test and so in the end, I want to see if I run the test 1000 times, what is the probability of rejecting null hypothesis when it is TRUE. Also, how do I plot the behavior of type I error if I change the values of standard deviations?

Answer (score 1):

You reject when $p\le\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ like $0.05$, right? When do you that over the course of the $1000$ iterations, how many rejections do you have?

If the test is doing what it claims, you will have about $1000\alpha$ rejections of the true null hypothesis, so $\sim50$ rejections at the $0.05$-level.

I have not done this for a random effects model, but I have gotten into a habit of plotting the empirical CDF of all of the p-values from my simulations like this. This is a way to visualize the type I error rate across a spectrum of $\alpha$-levels.

**EDIT**

I will demonstrate this with a t-test.

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100 # sample size
R <- 1000 # Number of repetitions 
ps <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){

    # Simulate draws from two equal distributions
    #
    x <- rnorm(N)
    y <- rnorm(N)

    # Run the t-test
    #
    ps[i] <- t.test(x, y, var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
}

# Plot the p-value CDF, along with y = x line 
#
plot(ps, ecdf(ps)(ps))
abline(0, 1)

# State type I error rates at common levels
# alpha = 0.10
# alpha = 0.05
# alpha = 0.01
#
print(paste("Type I error rate at 0.10-level is:", ecdf(ps)(0.10)))
print(paste("Type I error rate at 0.05-level is:", ecdf(ps)(0.05)))
print(paste("Type I error rate at 0.01-level is:", ecdf(ps)(0.01)))
```

Comment: Hi @Dave Thank you for the comments. Can you show some code of how to implement this in R? Or maybe you can just share the code you have done from your own simulation? Much appreciated!

Comment: @cliu I gave a basic example that I am hopeful you can adapt to your particular test.

Comment: Very good. Thank you @Dave!